# VB to Python Conversion Attempt

Tags: python, vb6

I am tasked with attempting to convert vb to python at my job.  I don't actually have to complete it but try and see if I can.  I've found an excellent resource here : http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/docs/dim.html

I'm only just learning Python so I am not an expert but thought this might be an interesting exercise.  This is designed for use in ArcGIS.

```
Public Property Get PageLayout_NewPolygon() As UID
    # from reference : There is also no concept of Public or 
    # Private class members in Python. Everything is public...
    # Original VB Next Line - Commented Out
    # Dim u As New UID
    # Python Next Line - Reference : http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/docs/dim.html
    u = UID()
    u = "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" # Value Changed.
    # Original VB Next Line - Commented Out
    # Set PageLayout_NewPolygon = u
    # Python Next Line - Reference : http://vb2py.sourceforge.net/docs/set.html
    PageLayout_NewPolygon = u
End Property
# I don't think 'End' is needed in Python so this can be removed, right?
```

Original Code : (To prevent confusion).

```
Public Property Get PageLayout_NewPolygon() As UID
    Dim u As New UID
    obj = Collection()
    u = "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" ' Value Changed.
    Set PageLayout_NewPolygon = u
End Property
```

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Is this just a thought-exercise? Or are you expecting to actually run the new code somehow?

Comment: It's a little routing program that consists of four files.  I'm just looking at one to see if I can convert it.  The first file has about 50 of the above where PageLayout_NewPolygon() is replaced with another variable. I'm hoping to run it! :)

Comment: In that case, you might want to take a look at what the program is doing *as a whole* and re-creating that, rather than trying to convert every line of VB into a line of Python.

Comment: Okay, Tom.  Do you have any advice on learning how to build an action plan for a python project?  It has been explained to me what it does but I might need to design a flow chart to wrap my head around it!

Comment: It sounds like you have a good idea already - spend some time working out exactly what the existing code does (try not to focus too much on how it does it though), and then you can decide if the overall layout is sensible/appropriate. If it is then you can follow a similar design (e.g. a similar flowchart), or you might decide to do something radically different. Try to decompose the existing app into functional areas and see if you can create each one in isolation. Good luck and have fun!